# declaration of point structure

Tags: c++

guys i have a one question relates to  point structure declaration,when i  was reading  tutorial about geometric data types declaration  ,i have seen two strange things which  confused me, i will  show these things right know

```
typedef double point[DIMENSION];
typedef struct {
    int n;          /* number of points in polygon */
    point p[MAXPOLY];   /* array of points in polygon */
} polygon;


typedef struct {
    point p1,p2;        /* endpoints of line segment */
} segment;

typedef point triangle[3];  /* triangle datatype */
```

let us  suppose that  dimension is some number for example (2) and maxpoly maxsimum number of points in polygon,i am confused with declaration of point
what does this means typedef double point[dimension]?,i know what is  typedef ,but in case of we declare  point as  double array,then how can we  use it in another structure

or class as a object?like   struct array?
consider this

```
typedef truct 
{
point p1,p2;
}segment;
```

how correct it is?please help me to understand this

Comment: You code does not contain any #define, yet you are asking about a #define.

Comment: The `#define` in your question, is it really correct? It's a terrible idea to change the meaning of keywords using the pre-processor.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the meanings of `#define` and `typedef`? Those are two different things.

Comment: This is hardly worth calling C++. What's with the typedefing of structs?

Comment: sorry it was typo downvote for this?it should be typedef  sorry

Comment: yes #define i have wrote incorrectly it should be typedef

Comment: Then edit the question and fix the typos. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: people who downvote based on the fact that asker doesn't understand something need to rethink their core values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something defined using `typedef` is just an alias (i.e. another name) of another type.

In your case

```
typedef double point[DIMENSION];
```

This defines the name `point` to mean "an array of size DIMENSION of the type double".

After this, instead of writing

```
double my_point[DIMENSION];
```

You can write

```
point my_point;
```

If the typedef is in a header file, the name can be used in all source and header files including the header file with the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define double point[dimension]
```

means that a point is 2 doubles in 2 dimensions, 3 in 3, etc.
But you should not be looking at that!!!!
The whole point of an OO language is that you don't need to know the internal details of a class.  You just need to know the API - how to use it.

In fact the class overloads operators so assignment works, etc.  You can use point in a struct just like any other class.  C++ allows nested structs or arrays of structs.

Comment: I wouldn't touch an API that redefines a built-in type.

Comment: I don't know what tutorial dato was reading and the original question has been edited now, but I assume it was just for teaching purposes.  Most likely the tutorial was originally in C.